# The sum of 1+(1-2)+(1-2+3)+(1-2+3-n)... where even integers are -k and odd integers are +k

Tags: c

I want to write a program where a user tells me an integer(n) and i calculate The sum of  1+(1-2)+(1-2+3)+(1-2+3-n)... where even integers are -k and odd integers are +k.

Ive made a function which does that But the sum is never correct. For example for n=2 it should be sum=0 but shows sum=-1 for n=3 should be sum=+2 but i shows sum=3. (Ignore the debugging printfs)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int athroismaAkolouthias(int n); // i sinartisi me tin opoia ypologizete to athroisma akolouthias 1+(1-2)+(1-2+3)+(1-2+3-4).....

int main(){
    int n;
    printf("give n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("the sum is %d", athroismaAkolouthias(n));
}

int athroismaAkolouthias(int n){
    int sum1=0, sum2=0,sum=0;
    int i, temp, j;
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++){
        for (j=1; j<=i; j++){
            temp=j;
        }
        if (i%2==0){sum=sum-temp; printf("test1 %d%d",sum,temp);}
        else{sum=temp; printf("test2 %d%d",sum,temp);}
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: It is better to copy your source code instead of an image of it. Doing this will help us to run and test it locally.

Comment: Also the loop over `j` seems incorrect because it will set `temp` equals to `i` at the end.

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to include your code as **text** rather than as a screenshot? On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with our loop which iterate with `j`, it should update the `inner_sum` based on `j` even/odd condition as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int akl(int n) {
  int sum = 0;

  for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    int inner_sum = 0;
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
      if (j % 2 == 0) {
        inner_sum -= j;
      } else {
        inner_sum += j;
      }
    }
    sum += inner_sum;
  }

  return sum;
}

int main() {
  int n;

  scanf("%d", &n);

  printf("%d\n", akl(n));
}
```

You only need two variables for `sum` that I named them `inner_sum` and `sum` which shows the sum of each term and sum over all terms.

Answer (score 0):

Suspicious Line:   `else {sum = temp; ...`

Shouldn't you be adding or subtracting to `sum` every time??
Why are you assigning to it here, without an addition or subtraction?

You also have variables `sum`, `sum1`, and `sum2`.
You print `sum1` and `sum2`, but never modify them.

---

Here's my solution:

```
// The sum of 1+(1-2)+(1-2+3)+(1-2+3-n)... where even integers are -k and odd integers are +k.
#include <stdio.h>

int ancho(int n)
{
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=1; i<=n; ++i)
    {
        for(int j=1; j<=i; ++j)
        {
            sum += (2*(j%2)-1)*j;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

int main(void)
{
    int n = 5;
    
    printf("Solution is %d\n", ancho(n));
}

// Solution is 3 for n = 5, 
// because: 1 + (1-2) + (1-2+3) + (1-2+3-4) + (1-2+3-4+5) = 
// 1-1+2-2+3 = 3
```

### Output

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 5476KB
Solution is 3
```

### [IDEOne Link](https://ideone.com/z1mwCs)